# Prove that if $f$ is non-negative and measurable and $\int fd\mu<\infty$, then $f<\infty$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if $f$ is non-negative and measurable and 
>   $\int fd\mu<\infty$, then $f<\infty$ a.e.
>
> > Here is my proof:
> >     If not, suppose that there exists $\mu(A)>0$ where $A=\{x: f(x)=\infty\}$. Then
> >     $$\infty>\int f > \int_{A}f>\infty\cdot\mu(A)$$
> >     which is a contradiction.

Is this method right?

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, let $A$ be a set of positive measure such that $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in A$ and let $\mathcal G(f)=\{g:X\to\Bbb R\,:\, g\text{ is simple }\land \forall x, f(x)\ge g(x)\}$. It is apparent that $n\cdot 1_A\in \mathcal G(f)=\mathcal G(f^+)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and therefore $$\int f\,d\mu=\sup_{g\in \mathcal G(f)} \sum_{h\in g[X]} h \mu(g^{-1}(h))\ge\sup_{n\in\Bbb N} n\mu(A)=\infty$$